# download/mirror a website on cloudflare for archiving

Tags: wget, archive, httrack

Trying to backup ( download / mirror ) a website for archival purposes. This site is apparently on Cloudflare. My usual tool for this would be `wget`, but it fails on me (even when using a cookie cfduid header). Example of a not-working `wget` command:

> wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0"  --header="Accept: text/html" --header="Cookie: __cfduid=someverylongcfduid" --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent -w 1m [www.domain.tld](http://www.domain.tld)

So I thought I'd return to my trusty friend `httrack`, but it too fails (even when using exported cookies). Example of a not-working `httrack` command:

> httrack -F "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0" --mirror -b1 -s0 -%c1 -c1 --referer "https://www.domain.tld/" "https://www.domain.tld/"

I do not want to pound the website, so limiting connections and waiting is quite OK. I'd rather have it run longer/slower and be a good [netizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netizen) along the way.

Currently I'm confronted with either [301 (Moved permanently)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) or [403 (Forbidden)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) errors and I'm assuming this is due to Cloudflare. The site is heavy on javascript :-(
Does anyone have any tips/advice/solution to get such a website archived?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using selenium.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.